# Creating Expression with out parameter and nullable types

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to build an expression that will call a method with an out parameter. So far I've had success, except when it comes to nullable versions of the parameters.

For this purpose lets suppose the `int.TryParse(string, out int)` method. I've successfully been able to build an expression (no nullables) by defining a delegate type for this purpose:

`internal delegate bool TestDelegate(string input, out int value);`

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethod()
{
    return typeof(int).GetMethod("TryParse", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int).MakeByRefType() }, null);
}

public static void NormalTestExpression()
{
    var method = GetMethod();

    var pValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "str");
    var pOutput = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), "value");

    var call = Expression.Call(method, pValue, pOutput);
    var lamd = Expression.Lambda<TestDelegate>(call, pValue, pOutput);
    var func = lamd.Compile();

    int output;
    var result = func("3", out output);
    // THIS WORKS!!!
}
```

I am trying to make this work with nullable types. Take for example:

`internal delegate bool TestNullableDelegate(string input, out int? value);`

The below will fail with an Argument Exception (`GetMethod()` is retrieving the correct method based off of the primitive type--same method from above)

```
public static void WithNullableTypeFails()
{
    var method = GetMethod();

    var pValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "str");
    var pOutput = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int?).MakeByRefType(), "value");
value
    var call = Expression.Call(method, pValue, pOutput); //Argument Exception int.TryParse() doesn't accept int? argument

    var lamd = Expression.Lambda<TestNullableDelegate>(call, pValue, pOutput);
    var func = lamd.Compile();

}


Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Int32' of method 'Boolean TryParse(System.String, Int32 ByRef)'
```

Now I am aware that this is because I am still invoking the MethodInfo which is taking the primitive `int` type and the delegates aren't matching. So I tried the below:

```
public static void WithNullableTypeAttempt()
{
    var method = GetMethod();

    var pValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "str"); 
    var pOutput = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int?).MakeByRefType(), "value");

    var vars = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "tmp");
    var resultvar = Expression.Variable(typeof(bool), "result");

    var call = Expression.Call(method, pValue, vars);
    var block = Expression.Block(
                        Expression.Assign(vars, Expression.Constant(default(int))), 
                        Expression.Assign(resultvar, call), 
                        Expression.Assign(pOutput, Expression.Convert(vars, typeof(int?))),
                        resultvar
                );
    var lamd = Expression.Lambda<TestNullableDelegate>(block, pValue, pOutput);
    var func = lamd.Compile(); // Invalid Operation Exception
}
```

I get an invalid operation exception when I attempt to compile it:

```
variable 'tmp' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

When I open the expression in one of the expression tree visualizers I have, I see the following:

```
(valueToParse, value) =>
{
    var tmp = 0;
    var result = int.TryParse(valueToParse, out tmp);
    var value = (int?)tmp;
    return result;
}
```

So I think I am on the right track.

How can I call this method where the types vary only by the Nullable type, keeping the delegate with the Nullable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using an [overload of the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324086(v=vs.110).aspx) that does not support variables.

Quoting from the reference above:

> Creates a BlockExpression that contains four expressions and has no variables.

You need to tell the block expression about the variables by using [an overload that supports variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323917(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var block = Expression.Block(
                    new ParameterExpression[] { vars, resultvar }, //variables
                    Expression.Assign(vars, Expression.Constant(default(int))),
                    Expression.Assign(resultvar, call),
                    Expression.Assign(pOutput, Expression.Convert(vars, typeof(int?))),
                    resultvar);
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw that overload in IntelliSense but didn't think anything of it. I'm still learning Expressions so it really didn't mean anything to me. Is this the best/only way for me to do this or is there any other way?  (PS In a meeting, will try in a few)

Comment: I am assuming that `TryParse` is just an example, and in reality, the method it self is not known at compile time right?

Comment: `TryParse` was an example. For this particular case I actually know the Method's name and have a MethodInfo but didn't want to Invoke on it; It's also happening inside of a generic class

Comment: I am asking to see if you actually need to build the expression manually instead of using a lambda expression.